Sabre Geosearch - how to use Polygon to search for hotels please?
I am trying to use the Sabre API from their postman collection
https://webservices.sabre.com
Here is the XML for request - but HOW DO I SPECIFY A POLYGON IN IT?
{{header}}

<GetHotelAvailRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/avail/v3_0_0" version="3.0.0">
    <SearchCriteria OffSet="1" SortBy="TotalRate" SortOrder="ASC" PageSize="200" >
        <GeoSearch>
            <GeoRef Radius="20" UOM="MI">
                <RefPoint Value="900000855" ValueContext="CODE" RefPointType="37"/>
            </GeoRef>
        </GeoSearch>
        <RateInfoRef CurrencyCode="USD" BestOnly="2" PrepaidQualifier="IncludePrepaid">
            <StayDateRange StartDate="{{start_date}}" EndDate="{{short_end_date}}"/>
            <Rooms>
                <Room Index="1" Adults="1" Children="0"/>
            </Rooms>
            <InfoSource>100,111,112,110</InfoSource>
        </RateInfoRef>
        <HotelPref>
        </HotelPref>
        <ImageRef Type="MEDIUM" LanguageCode="EN"/>
    </SearchCriteria>
</GetHotelAvailRQ>

{{footer}}

Tried to look for samples and documentation but did not find any

The Code "900000855" Under GeoSearch.GeoRef.RefPoint Represents the Polygon ID in which the search needs to take place.
